# Extracting attribute parameter values

Tags: c#, reflection, nunit, custom-attributes

I can retrieve all of the test names out of an NUnit test class library assembly, but I need to retrieve their category names as well from the parameter passed to the `Category` attribute.

For example:

```
[Category("text")] 
public void test() {}
```

I need to get `"text"` from the DLL.

Comment: If the answer is right for you, please mark it as correct. This helps other people to find the solution faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection.

For example:

Given this attribute applied to fields:

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)> _
     Public NotInheritable Class DataBaseValueAttribute
    Inherits Attribute

    Private _value As Object

    Public Sub New(ByVal value As Object)
      _value = value
    End Sub

    Public Function GetValue() As Object
      Return _value
    End Function
  End Class
```

You can use reflection to get field info from a type and get the attributes:

```
Dim tipo As Type = GetType(YourType)
Dim fi As FieldInfo = tipo.GetField("fieldName")

Dim attribs As Atributos.DataBaseValueAttribute() = CType(fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(Atributos.DataBaseValueAttribute), False), Atributos.DataBaseValueAttribute())
If attribs.Count > 0 Then
   Return attribs(0).GetValue()
Else
   Return Nothing
End If
```

In c#:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public sealed class DataBaseValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    private object _value;
    public DataBaseValueAttribute(object value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public object GetValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}

Type tipo = typeof(YourType);
FieldInfo fi = tipo.GetField("fieldName");

Atributos.DataBaseValueAttribute[] attribs = (Atributos.DataBaseValueAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Atributos.DataBaseValueAttribute), false);
if (attribs.Count > 0) {
    return attribs(0).GetValue();
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: jlvaquero, thank you for answer!=) but can you please write in c#?

Comment: OK. I post C# because I forgot to chek the language tag of your question.